# Displaying two Selects under eachother that both have float right

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/92BQK/

What am i doing wrong?

I am giving responsible a separate P because i know that devResp will be the full width of the container, while devImage for sure wont be

```
<p>Responsible: </p>
 <p>
   <select id="devResp" style="float:right">
     <option>ULTIEMETESTHOEREN</option>
   </select>
 </p>
 <p>
  Image:
   <select id ="devImage" style ="float:right">
     <option></option>
   </select>
 </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `clear: right` within the style of the second `select`.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/92BQK/2/

**Code:**

```
<p>Responsible: </p> 
<p>
    <select id="devResp" style="float:right">
        <option>ULTIEMETESTHOEREN</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>Image:
    <select id ="devImage" style ="float:right; clear: right;">
        <option></option>
    </select>    
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/92BQK/14/

```
<p  style="float:right" >
        Responsible: 
            <select id="devResp">    
                <option>ULTIEMETESTHOEREN</option>
            </select>
</p>

<div style="clear:right"></div>

<p style ="float:right">
    Image:
           <select id ="devImage" >
             <option></option>
           </select>
</p>
```